# Read until condition is met and read next line storing it as an array

Tags: c#

I currently have a conf file which exists out of the following format:

```
[client]
person1,person2,person3,person4

[employee]
emp1,emp2,emp3,mp4
```

And so on. Now I need to read the file to store the data that comes after the line [employee] into and array.

Comment: So what is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Can you explain your question in detail?

Comment: is this file a .INI file by chance..?

Comment: tried to continue the file line per line until == [employee], if that condition is met i need to read the next line to store it in an array. the issue atm is i dont know how to read the next line after the conditiopn is met.

Comment: what is the extension of the file you are trying to read.. simple question.. this does not look like a .Config File so I am assuming it's a .INI File

Comment: its a .dat file (plain text) but if needed it could be stored as either a .INI or Conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick draft, try something like this:

```
string[] readAllLines = File.ReadAllLines("path/to/file");
for (int i = 0; i < readAllLines.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (readAllLines[i].StartsWith("[employee]"))
    {
        string[] employees = readAllLines[i + 1].Split(',');
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

Comment: Doesn't seem as if the error comes from my code. Tweaked it a bit anyway. I tested it with your example and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Untested Code:

```
static class SubstringExtensions
{  

    /// <summary>
    /// Get string value after [last] a.
    /// </summary>
    public static string After(this string value, string a)
    {
    int posA = value.LastIndexOf(a);
    if (posA == -1)
    {
        return "";
    }
    int adjustedPosA = posA + a.Length;
    if (adjustedPosA >= value.Length)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return value.Substring(adjustedPosA);
    }
}
```

Read the File:

```
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
myFile.Close();
string[] split = myString.After("[employee]").Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most cool or elegant way, but the way you described it would work like this.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("path to your config file");
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf("[employee]"), 25);
text = text.Replace("[employee]\r\n", "");

string[] array = text.Split(',');
```

Comment: Seems to work like a charm, altho it continues reading to the end of the file and prints [remote] and the text under remote]